# Sort Database object

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a UITableView each cell shows unique menu item I want items to be sort in my list but those menu items are not coming from an array but from a db object

Example:

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath{
  Menus_Items *menuItem = [menuCategory.hasMenuItems.allObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  lblMenuItemName.text = menuItem.name;

}
```

How can I sort menu items ? I could have done it if it was an array i.e.

```
NSSortDescriptor *orderSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order" ascending:NO];
// String are alphabetized in ascending order
NSSortDescriptor *strNameSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

// Combine the two
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[orderSort, strNameSort];

arrCategories = [DatabaseHelper getAllData:@"Menus_cat" offset:0 predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ofOutlet == %@",outletsObject] sortDescriptor:nil];

// sortedArrayUsingDescriptor is the method use to sort an array which is having multiple parameters in sort descriptor
arrCategories = [arrCategories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Help please. Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you sort while you're fetching ?

Comment: i tried but its in loop it didn't work out well

Comment: Show us the rest of the code...

Comment: There's not enough information for anyone to help. Describe the objects you want to sort, how you want them sorted, where you're getting them from, and what problems you had when trying to sort them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`menuCategory.hasMenuItems.allObjects` is an array so you can sort it to get the appropriate item. You could sort it each time or keep a sorted cache of the content. Neither of these options is ideal.

Really, you want to use a fetch request with a sort descriptor, ideally managed by a fetch request controller. Usually you would do that by using the relationship 'backwards'. So, you create the fetch and set the predicate to `XXX = %@`, where XXX is the relationship name and the supplied parameter is `menuCategory`.

This is assuming the relationship is 1:many, if it's many:many you will need a different predicate form.